# domain.store/category/entry

Tags: ee2, cartthrob

How do I achieve this? I need to have the domain/category/entry

eg. clothes.store/t-shirts/red-t-shirt

I'm using EE2.11.1, and Carthrob, But I don't know how to achieve that url.

I only know how to get clothes.store/products/t-shirts/red-t-shirt

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use template routes. This is an EE native function but requires you read the docs well.

Boyink has an intro that will be beneficial [here](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/introduction-to-template-routes-for-expressionengine)

With the official syntax described in the EE docs [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html) - it's version 3 doc's but syntax is the same for ee2.

Answer (score -1):

what's your category url indicator?

Comment: Not too sure. This is a new build. I've just never done urls where the segment one is a category so unsure how to deal with the templating etc. Do you have a way I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: You can use freebie to eliminate the required use of a category indicator segment. And use switchee to build your logic in the templates. It can be somewhat daunting.

Comment: If you need some more help hit me on twitter @ome_jelle